# How can i open/close bootstrap dialog in typescript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am using type script with plain html. 
I want to open and close bootstrap modal from type script function.

※JQuery already included and accessible.

```
function showDialog() {
    $('#settings').modal('show');
}

function hideDialog() {
    $('#settings').modal('hide');
}
```

[image: modal() gives error : Propery modal does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.]